# My api.search function does not return any result at all. Do I need to have an approved Twitter Developer account for the code to work?

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I've recently applied a Twitter developer account for a school project. While I'm trying to extract / get tweets that match a specific set of keywords, the api.search() does not return any result at all. Do I need to get an approved Twitter Developer account? Because after I applied and confirmed my application I haven't heard from them so I'm not sure if my account got approved at all.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
 auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)
    csvFile = open('tweetget', 'a')
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
    search_words = "pandemic,government,covid,COVID-19,lockdown,mask"      #enter your words
    new_search = search_words + " -filter:retweets"

    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=new_search,count=100, lang="en",since_id=0).items():
          csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf 
          8'),tweet.user.screen_name.encode('utf-8'), tweet.user.location.encode('utf-8')])
```

Answer (score 1):

Account invalid or not verified would get a 401 status code (unauthorised).

To test your account can fetch data you could try

```
# print followers
api = tweepy.API(auth)
for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers).items():
     print(follower.name)
```

The issue might be the query string. If you want to search for tweets with ANY of the key words the search query would be:

```
search_words = "pandemic OR government OR covid OR COVID-19 OR lockdown OR mask"
new_search = search_words + " -filter:retweets"
```

For searching tweets matching ALL key words you can use spaces (also comma delimiter works too)

```
search_words = "pandemic government covid COVID-19 lockdown mask"
new_search = search_words + " -filter:retweets"
```

In your case I don't think there is a Tweet with all keywords you search for: try to reduce the list of keywords to verify.

See [Building Queries](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/labs/recent-search/guides/search-queries) documentation

Comment: Yes, I agree with this. Having a search string delimited with commas is probably the issue in the original question.